# How do I get values from a textfield and save it in an integer array that later displays it in a label

Tags: java, arrays, string, netbeans

I have been getting errors with this code 
my output displays in symbols
I am using Java in netbeans gui builder

```
   String[] stringValues = jTextField1.getText().split("[,]");
        int[] numArray= new int[stringValues.length];

        for(int i=0; i<numArray.length; i++){
        numArray[i]= Integer.parseInt(stringValues[i]);
        }

        String value ="";
        for (int j = 0; j <= numArray.length; j++) {
        value += numArray[j];}
        jLabel1.setText( value.toString() );
```

Comment: what error do you get ? Could you add an exemple of input and output you get and output you expect ?

Comment: In your second for loop you write `j <= numArray.length` there you become a IndexOutOfBoundException. Write instead: `j < numArray.length`

Comment: hi i have been getting an output of @[2371

Comment: i want to have a user input 1,2,3,4 and save it into an int array then have the array display in a label 1,2,3,4

Comment: @Morchul i will try that now

Comment: @Kimberly your output is `@[2371` cause you display `value.toString()`. And value is of type String. If you want to display its content directly print `value`. Calling `toString()` on a String object displays its reference (kind of memory address), that's `@[2371`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this:

```
String[] stringValues = jTextField1.getText().split(",");
//split the input "1,2,3,4" by "," result in array = ["1","2","3","4"]

int[] numArray= new int[stringValues.length];


for(int i=0; i<numArray.length; i++){
    numArray[i]= Integer.parseInt(stringValues[i]);
    //parse every string to int
}

String value ="";
for (int j = 0; j < numArray.length; j++) {
    value += numArray[j] + ",";
    //for each int in numArray ad: "numArray[j],"
}
//result is = "1,2,3,4,"

value = value.substring(0, value.length() - 1);
//remove last unused ","

jLabel1.setText( value );
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code from ->

```
        String[] stringValues = jTextField1.getText().split("[,]");
        int[] numArray= new int[stringValues.length];

        for(int i=0; i<numArray.length; i++){
          numArray[i]= Integer.parseInt(stringValues[i]);
        }

        String value ="";

        for (int j = 0; j <= numArray.length; j++) {
          value += numArray[j];
        }

        jLabel1.setText( value.toString() );
```

to this ->

```
    String[] stringValues = jTextField1.getText().split("[,]");
    int[] numArray= new int[stringValues.length];

    for(int i=0; i<numArray.length; i++){
       numArray[i]= Integer.parseInt(stringValues[i]);
    }

    String value = "";

    for (int j = 0; j < numArray.length; j++) {
      value += Integer.toString(numArray[j]) + ",";
    }

    jLabel1.setText(value);
```

Comment: Could you add explanations ? so the OP will understand why his code isn't and why your code is

Comment: added the explanation of cause of problem and answer as well.

Comment: I'm not sure he want to see the sum of the values. In his question he says: "in an integer array that later displays it in a label". So I think he want to see the integer array well formated like: ``5,4,3,6``. But I'm not sure maybe you are right.

Comment: sorry, i will change it according to it.

Comment: hi i tried running this it is giving me an error ----> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
 at assignment1.test.jButton1ActionPerformed(test.java:273)
 at assignment1.test.access$000(test.java:13)
 at assignment1.test$1.actionPerformed(test.java:84)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel..............

Comment: I have changed the code now, which won't give you indexoutofbound Exception, because... we are looping over the length of the array.

Comment: @Kimberly check [Morchul comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348333/how-do-i-get-values-from-a-textfield-and-save-it-in-an-integer-array-that-later/50348452?noredirect=1#comment87712556_50348333), that's why you get this error

Comment: yes, you are right @vincrichaud, and i have changed it in my code.

Comment: @Kimberly well, my code certainly works, i have checked it.